# Why are my extern variables not initialized?

Tags: c, gcc

I use the following pattern in my shared libraries:

```
extern int var;
...
int var = -1;
...
void _module_init(void) {
  if (var < 0) {
    ... do initialization stuff ...
    var = [some generated value > 0]
  }
}
...
void module_api_function( ... parameters ... ) {
  _module_init();
  ... stuff ...
}
```

This worked perfectly, until I redid my cmake makefiles a bit (got rid of static libraries - I used to build both a shared and a static lib). For some reason now `var` isn't being initialized to `-1` anymore, but is now `0`. Other, pointer, `extern` variables are set to `NULL`. My `static` variables seem to initialize OK. And to make this even more infuriating, some of my shared libraries work and others don't. And linux/gcc 6.0.2 doesn't work, but Windows/MingW/gcc 4.x does work.

I'm tearing my hair out. My current working theory is that something runs before `main` and clobbers my data segment. But this is C, so I don't know what that can be.

What am I missing? Is there a tool in the `nm`/`readelf`/`objdump` family that will show me not only the address of exported symbols but also their value? Is there something in gcc 6.0 that's tripping me up?

Confused.

*Edit:* Some preemptive remarks:

- The variable `var` is part of the module's API. Can't make it `static`
- I'm aware of `__attribute__((constructor))`, but I want to keep my options open to port to MSVC at some point. Also not really relevant to the problem at hand

*Edit 2*: CMakeLists.txt for the failing lib, but the others are roughly the same:

```
set(SOURCES
    any.c
    array.c
    ... about 20 more ...
)

# I ripped off the regex API from glibc for use on Windows.
if (NOT HAVE_REGEX_H)
    set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} regex.c)
endif (NOT HAVE_REGEX_H)

add_library(oblcore SHARED ${SOURCES})

if (NOT HAVE_REGEX_H)
    target_compile_definitions(oblcore PRIVATE BUILD_REGEX_DLL;HAVE_CONFIG_H)
endif (NOT HAVE_REGEX_H)

install(TARGETS oblcore
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)

add_subdirectory(test)
```

Comment: Can you post your CMakeLists.txt file?